# How to save a file through telnet POST REQUEST?

Tags: http, post, https, telnet

when i type in a certain link in the URL example:

```
https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth/request_token?oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT&oauth_consumer_key=asdfasdfasdfasdf&oauth_signature=asdfasdfasdf%26
```

i will automatically download a file returned from the website.

How do i do the same in TELNET?

For this URL i have to use POST, so i made the following commands:

```
POST https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth/request_token?oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT&oauth_consumer_key=asdfasdfasdfasdf&oauth_signature=asdfasdfasdf%26
```

However what commands should i add to save that returned file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try curl or wget instead of telnet.

Technically it should be possible to dump the output from telnet, cut out the body, do the transcoding, etc, but I don't see how this is simpler or more portable than curl or wget.

Comment: agreed! i moved on to libcurl.